# How to dynamically create order_by statements and inject them into flasksqlalchemy query

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to dynamically create an order_by statement using flask-sqlalchemy query.

This is a call of my PurchaseOrder method:

```
pos = PurchaseOrder.get_all_pos(column_order=['id', 'due_date'])
```

column_order can have one or more columns which we used to sort the result of the query.

```
class PurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderDB):

    @classmethod
    def get_all_pos(cls, **kwargs):
        columns = kwargs.pop('column_order', '')
        columns_order = [getattr(cls, column) for column in columns]
        if len(columns_order) != 0:
            pos = cls.query.order_by(columns_order).all()
        else:
            pos = cls.query.all()
        return pos
```

columns_order is a list of InstrumentedAttributes, and when I pass that list to order_by() method I get as I expected the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type <class 'list'> instead
```

So, is there some other way to dynamically create order_by when we don't know how many columns are passed in? 
In this situation query should look like:

```
pos = cls.query.order_by(cls.id, cls.due_date).all()
```

Comment: Can't test, so this is a shot in the dark, hence just a comment for now: You could try mapping the column list [as textual representation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) using [text()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) and then use unpacking: `from sqlalchemy import text; cls.query.order_by(*map(text, columns_order)).all()`

Comment: This works. I've used text() method to create columns order. Now I pass string(not list) as `columns_order = 'id, due_date'` and pass that string to my classmethod and just use text(columns_order) to sort in order in which columns names were passed.

Comment: Cool, thanks for giving it a try. Feel free to post an answer with this solution. I'll hardly find the time to do so within the next 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this using text() method (as @shmee note in the comment of the above question).

I've change parameter type which was passed as column_order (now it is a string)

```
pos = PurchaseOrder.get_all_pos(column_order='id, due_date')
```

You can also use asc or desc (ascending or descending) order for each column, just after each column name:

```
pos = PurchaseOrder.get_all_pos(column_order='id desc, due_date asc')
```

Also I've made some refactoring of my method, so now it works fine.

```
class PurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderDB):

    @classmethod
    def get_all_pos(cls, **kwargs):
        columns_order = kwargs.pop('columns_order', '')
        if columns_order:
            return cls.query.order_by(text(columns_order)).all()
        else:
            return cls.query.all()
```

Here is the text() documentation:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text

> Also, the text.text argument to text() can be passed as a Python
>   string argument, which will be treated as trusted SQL text and
>   rendered as given. DO NOT PASS UNTRUSTED INPUT TO THIS PARAMETER.

That means that you have to pass only trusted SQL string. In my situation, I pass only hardcoded string. If you for example use string that came from the user of your app, that string can contain some unwanted SQL injection.

So always validate that user-defined string.

Comment: `len(columns_order) != ''` will always be true. You probably want to drop the `len()` or test for `!= 0`.

Comment: I forgot to change that. I've just edited my answer. Now I only check if it is empty string or not.

Comment: I like your second edit. Testing for the truthiness of the string is more pythonic than what I proposed. Please consider adding a link to the documentation for `text()` to your post; it contains an important warning: *DO NOT PASS UNTRUSTED INPUT TO THIS PARAMETER*. Maybe you should even add that warning directly to your post, so that others are aware. I'll happily upvote your answer if you do so. Also, remember to accept your answer once the 48 hour wait period has elapsed ;)